# Ionic - vertical align image in ion-slide-box

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic `ion-slide-box` control to display couple of images. Each image has a different height. I'm struggling to center vertically images inside these slides. Right now entire slide is aligned to top:

[image]

```
<ion-slide-box>
    <ion-slide>
        <img src="../../img/article1.png">
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <div style="height: 100%">
            <img src="../../img/article111.png">
        </div>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <img src="../../img/article1111.png">
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Comment: Please create a demo of your code using http://play.ionic.io

Comment: @ManojKumar http://play.ionic.io/app/b3399996e760
You have 3 pictures with different height. I want all of them to be vertical align middle.

Comment: I think that whole ion--slide has to be centered in relation to slider.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define a few styles for your slider.

First of all we need to set the slider full screen (considering there's an header):

```
.slider {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

then we need to center the image in each slider:

```
.slider-slide
{
  text-align: center;  
}
```

and last we need to center vertically:

```
.slider-slide img {
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can see how it works [here](http://play.ionic.io/app/49cc1e8e4667).

PS: I've prepared a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zqWWSken4o3sx3DVE2FW?p=preview) as well cause it's easier to see how the slider works.

Comment: I had to add position: relative to .slider and this worked kind of, but the height was a little too tall going off screen, so I made some offsets to the height. Otherwise, this worked like a charm

Comment: If you're happy with the answer could you, please, accept it? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 4

```
ion-slides{
  ion-slide{
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  }
}
```